# Hive CLI or Beeline > is it possible to override Hadoop properties through "--hiveconf"

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am using Hive CLI and Beeline, for both there is "--hiveconf" option. Is it possible to use this "--hiveconf" to set Hadoop properties?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correct you cannot set Hadoop properties using **-hiveconf**. It is strictly used to replace the variables in the query with some parameters.
For instance you have a generic query

> select * from ${hiveconf:table}

From the hive CLI you can pass the 'table' variable with any parameter like this

> Hive$> hive -hiveconf table=MyTable -e 'select * from ${hiveconf:table};'

here 'MyTable' is just any table. You can change the table name without changing the query. So **-hiveconf** is used to make the query more generic.
More over you can use **-d** instead of **-hiveconf** as well.

To set the Hadoop properties you need to use the **set** command which will be valid only for that session. Ex: To set the property to print the current db name in Hive, below is the command

> Hive$> set hive.cli.print.current.db=true

To override the Hadoop properties permanently you need to change **hive-site.xml** file